# python convert splitted dictionairy back to dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to index match with pandas using multiple dataframes. Right now I am trying to create these dataframe, but I have trouble formatting them.

Currently the code I am using splits each dataframe with the function `df.to_dict('split')` and pastes it into a dictionairy. when I then try to retreive this data from the dictionairy and concat one dataframe for each one that was pasted in the dictionairy, I am getting the following result

```
Printing dfobj
                                                     0                                                1
index    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]             [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
columns  [Name, Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Close, Vol...  [Name, Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Close, Vol...
data     [[Orange, 20200430, 15:30:00, 5.7, 5.97, 5.65,...  [[Apple, 20200504, 10:00:00, 3.7, 3.97,  3.65, ...
```

I am having trouble formatting this back to a dataframe that says:

```
    Name      Date      Time  Open  High   Low  Close  Volume  VWAP  Trades
0   Orange  20200430  15:30:00  5.70  5.97  5.65   5.75    1000  5.60      55
1   Orange  20200430  17:00:00  5.65  5.95  5.50   5.80    1200  5.65      68
```

The sample code I am using to achive this is

```
import pandas as pd
import os

#Opening 'Test Tracker.xlsx' to find entities to download
TEST = pd.ExcelFile("Trackers\TEST Tracker.xlsx")
df1 = TEST.parse("Entries")

values1 = df1[['Name', 'Location', 'Date', 'TimeO', 'TimeC', 'Check_2',
           'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'VWAP', '$Volume', 'Trades']]

#Searching for every row that contains the value 'X' in the column 'Check_2'
rdf1 = values1[values1.Check_2.str.contains("X")]

#Printing dataframe to check
print("First Dataframe")
print(rdf1)

#creating a dictionary for the dataframes
Fruits = {}

#Generating dataframes from classobjects
for idx, rows in rdf1.iterrows():
    fle = os.path.join('Entities', rows.Location, rows.Name, 'TwoHours.csv')
    col_list = ['Name', 'Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'VWAP', 'Trades']
    df3 = pd.read_csv(fle, usecols=col_list, sep=";")
    Fruits['' + str(idx)] = df3.to_dict('split')

print("Printing Fruits Dictionairy")
print(Fruits)


columns = ['Name', 'Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'VWAP', 'Trades']
dfobj = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Fruits)

print("Printing dfobj")
print(dfobj)
```

Can someone here help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer or you have already found it but I will give you an example.
Let's say that your dictionairy looks like this (a smaller one).

```
diction = {'index':[0,1,2,3], 
           'columns':[['Name', 'Date', 'Time', 'Open'], 
                      ['Name', 'Date', 'Time', 'Open'], 
                      ['Name', 'Date', 'Time', 'Open'],
                      ['Name', 'Date', 'Time', 'Open']], 
           'data':[['Orange', '20200430','15:00:20',5.5],
                   ['Apple', '20201111','15:30:00',7.5],
                   ['Banana', '20200222','19:00:00',6.0],
                   ['Melon', '20200505','20:00:00',4.5]]}
```

Then to create a dataframe from this dictionairy you can try :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = diction['data'],columns = diction['columns'][0])

              
     Name      Date      Time  Open
0  Orange  20200430  15:00:20   5.5
1   Apple  20201111  15:30:00   7.5
2  Banana  20200222  19:00:00   6.0
3   Melon  20200505  20:00:00   4.5
```